# Can a last will and testament require successors to attend the funeral?

Tags: wills, probate

My spouse and I worry that my multi-millionaire grandparent will pass soon, and based on interactions with other family members, we suspect that the will could contain language that says that all of a successor's descendants must be present at the funeral in order for that successor to receive their portion of the inheritance.

Does this sort of thing happen? Is this enforceable in probate?

(For the record, we don't know or care if we would get any money ourselves. We are worried certain family members would try something drastic if their millions depended on our attendance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make a bequest conditional on an action to be performed before it is made, like attending a funeral.

Comment: A good example of what Dale is saying, I think, is [*Earle v. Angell*, 157 Mass. 294 (1892)](https://h2o.law.harvard.edu/collages/3978)

Comment: For another example see the movies [Dawg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawg_(film)) and [The Bachelor](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0120596/).